# What's the meaning and usage of "One such proposal is FOR" and "The concept is OF"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-request

Could you guys please explain about these sentences?

1. One such proposal is FOR the vertical farm.
2. The concept is OF multi-storey buildings

I can't understand about FOR and OF in these sentences.

'Many believe an entirely new approach to indoor farming is required, employing cutting-edge technologies. One such proposal is FOR the ‘Vertical Farm’. The concept is OF multi-storey buildings in which food crops are grown in environmentally controlled conditions.'

Can 'consist of' be used as the same meaning as 'be of' in this context? Are there any other words or terms to replace these words in this instance?

Comment: I tried to answer this question but couldn't. "For" and "of" have many definitions.

Comment: The collocation is "to **conceive of** something"  and this relationship of **of** to the verb persists in related nouns (conceive -> concept, conception).  The concept is of X, his conception of X...

Comment: And the subject of a proposal is often introduced by **for**.  "The city council are voting on a proposal *for* a new park."  "To **propose for**"  is the verbal collocation. That which is proposed is the complement/object of **for**.  "They proposed for the city to create a new park."

Answer (score 0):

There are so many definitions, but I would go with these:
[*for*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for_1):

> 10. *preposition*
>       You use **for** after nouns expressing reason or cause.
>       *He's soon to make a speech in parliament explaining his reasons for going.
>
>       The county hospital could find no physical cause for Sumner's problems.
>
>       He has now been formally given the grounds for his arrest.*

and [*of*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of_1):

> 8. *preposition*
>      You use *of* to indicate the materials or things that form something.
>      *...local decorations of wood and straw.
>
>      ...loose-fitting garments of linen.
>
>      ...a mixture of paint-thinner and petrol*.

To me, the better approach is to use alternate wording that is more specific and omits such ambiguous usage. For example:

The vertical farm is one such proposal.
The concept is <del>of</del> multi-storey buildings.